# Open DatePicker or DatePickerDialog using custom button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to trigger the DatePickerDialog to open using an external control / button other than the built in `input` that comes out of the box with the DatePicker?

We are using the [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-alpha.2/#/components/date-picker) library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the dialog `open` state is handled internally by `material-ui` components, the only way to do it would be using `ref` in the `DatePicker` and calling `focus()`. Kind of a hack - but it works..

Example:

```
<DatePicker
    ref='datePickerStartDate'
    errorStyle={componentSyles.error}
    textFieldStyle={componentSyles.textField}
    DateTimeFormat={Intl.DateTimeFormat}
    cancelLabel={cancelLabel}
    autoOk={true}
    {...this.props}
     />

<FontIcon
    onClick={(e) => { this.refs.datePickerStartDate.focus() }}
    className="material-icons" style={componentSyles.icon}>
    date_range
</FontIcon>
```

Comment: Hey this works great, thanks. One question: We're using this in a dynamically created list of items, each with a datepicker, and the context of the array index is always set to the last item in the array, but when we use it as an input, it works fine. Any how to pass in the correct index?

Comment: Have u tried to bind the index into that function? If so, could u provide some code?

Comment: FYI - this no longer works with React 16+