# How to invoke date picker from date input in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

[image]

I want to call it by clicking on a custom button. I already tried to use `elem.click` and `elem.focus`, but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open DatePicker or DatePickerDialog using custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628282/open-datepicker-or-datepickerdialog-using-custom-button)